# JavaScript icon pack won't fetch/download in Google Chrome (icons won't show)

Tags: javascript, html, web, icons, ionicons

I'm having this frustrating issue only on Google Chrome that it won't download my icon pack.
The pack I'm using is ionicon which is pretty straightforward considering its [documentation](https://ionic.io/ionicons/usage).
I followed the documentation carefully and the pack is working fine with most of the browser but chrome won't show any icon

Here is my footer that has just three icons.

```
    <footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul class="footer-lists">
      <li>
        <a class="icon" href="#"
          ><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="icon" href="#"
          ><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="icon" href="#"
          ><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon
        ></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: open the network tab and check if the browser is making any call to the `src`

Comment: Works absolutely fine in Chrome - you have got all the necessary dependencies referenced in your HTML?

Comment: Here's the thing with crhome ... sometimes (too often) it refuses to load a new version of a resource (html, js, css) and simply loads the cached version - perhaps that's the issue here

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius
the documentation just says to add the script before the body's closing tag. And so I did.

Comment: @brk It does and it fails to download it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

you must add the script after title tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).